# Por qué no se ve en miniatura las imagenes haciendo uso de js lightGallery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

estaba viendo la pagina oficial de lightGallery pero no logro encontrar o solucionar el problema con ver las fotos en minatura de esta forma:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando importe todas las librerías solo se me visualiza de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces que mas debería agregar?

Librerias de lightGallery:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.12/css/lightgallery.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.12/js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lg-thumbnail/1.1.0/lg-thumbnail.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lg-fullscreen/1.1.0/lg-fullscreen.min.js"></script>
```

Codigo donde llamo desde el controlador y visualizo cada imagen

```
@extends('plantilla')
@section('content')
<div id="aniimated-thumbnials">
   @foreach ($evidencias as $evidencia)
       @if($evidencia->url)
          <a href="{{ url($evidencia->url) }}">
            <img src="{{ url($evidencia->url) }}">
          </a>

       @endif
   @endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Si accedes a la web de [lightgallery](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/) e inspeccionas elemento sobre esa galería podrás ver los estilos clases que se les da a los elementos. Creo que copiarlo sería un buen punto de partida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes inicializar la librería de lightgallery apuntando al div donde estan metidas todas las fotos:

```
 $("#aniimated-thumbnials").lightGallery({
  thumbnail:true,
  mode:'lg-fade'});
```

en la página de la librería tienes un apartado de documentación, donde te aparece todas las opciones que puedes añadirle, incluso tiene un apartado de atributos personalizados donde ponérselo directamente en el html.Para el tema de tamaño de la imagen, sería lo mas propio por css, para que te salga con esa miniatura, si te fijas en el código en el modo desarrollador del navegador.De esa forma, te aparecerán en el tamaño que deseas y si pulsas, debería aparecer con el tamaño real de la foto.Puedes montar una clase genérica como ésta o crear un clase, como tu prefieras.

```
     img{
            height: 100px;
            width: 200px;
        }
```